# SQL Query Returns NULL as a Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to force an employee number when email address doesn't exist (is null) for a user. Regardless what I do, I always get NULL for the employee number in the result set. How do I force the employees number?

I have tried `CASE WHEN len(B.email) < 1 THEN '1234568'` This doesn't work.

I have tried `CASE WHEN C.EMPLOYEE = 1234568 /*(b/c employee exists)*/ THEN '1234568'` This doesn't work either.

I have also tried `NULLIF(B.email,'EMAIL')` This doesn't work either.

```
SELECT 
    EMPLOYEE, DATE, [JOB CODE], HM_ACCT_UNIT,
    CASE  
       WHEN SUM(HOURS) < '10.0' 
          THEN LEFT(REPLACE(SUM(ROUND(HOURS, 2)), '.', ''), 3)  
       WHEN SUM(HOURS) >= '10.0' 
          THEN LEFT(REPLACE(SUM(ROUND(HOURS, 2)), '.', ''), 4) 
       ELSE LEFT(REPLACE(SUM(ROUND(HOURS, 2)), '.', ''), 3) 
    END AS HOURS
FROM
    (SELECT
         CASE
            WHEN B.emaill = 'xx@some.com' THEN '123456'
            WHEN B.email = 'xy@some.com' THEN '123457'
            WHEN B.email IS NULL THEN '123458'
            ELSE RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, C.EMPLOYEE), 6)
         END AS 'EMPLOYEE',
         REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(a.start AS date), 101), '/', '') 'DATE',
         '14' as 'JOB CODE',
         -- CONVERT(int, REPLACE(dur, '.0', ''), 4) / 60 AS HOURS,
         CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), dur) / 60 AS HOURS,
         CASE
            WHEN A.project = 'SOMETHINGELSE' THEN '123'
            ELSE '12345' 
         END AS 'HM_ACCT_UNIT'
     FROM 
         [dbo].[project] A
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         [dbo].[user] B ON A.uid = B.uid
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         EMPLOYEE C ON RTRIM(LTRIM(C.EMAIL_ADDRESS)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(B.email))
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         GL D ON D.ACCT_UNIT = C.HM_ACCT_UNIT
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         [dbo].[projList] CPT ON LTRIM(RTRIM(CPT.[Capital Project])) = LTRIM(RTRIM(A.project))
     WHERE 
         CONVERT(CHAR(10), a.start, 103) >= DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE())
         AND (A.project LIKE '%SOMETHING%' OR A.project = 'SOMETHINGELSE')) A
GROUP BY 
    EMPLOYEE, DATE, [JOB CODE], HM_ACCT_UNIT
ORDER BY 
    DATE
```

My result set always returns this for one employee whose email is missing.

```
NULL    04072020    14  10XX202XX   5000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out if the value is NULL using `IS NULL`. For example:

```
CASE WHEN B.email is null THEN '1234568'
```

You can combine this predicate with other ones using `OR` to cover other similar cases. For example:

```
CASE WHEN len(B.email) < 1 or B.email is null THEN '1234568'
```

Comment: I neglected to mention that I tried the is null option and it didnt work. I have just tried your combining suggestion (WHEN (B.email is null OR  len(B.email) <1) ). This also give NULL in the result set.

Comment: Then, add sample data to your question, so we can reproduce the case.

Comment: Let me see how to best do that since its a culmination of a few tables.

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking this issue. The B.email was never null. I was mapping the B.email with C.EMAIL_ADDRESS. The issue is that the C.EMAIL_ADDRESS was null. I cant mark question as closed.